# How do I track PHP SOAP requests/response calls

Tags: php, soap, fiddler, bing-api

I'm using the Bing Adcenter API to pull out data from my Bing ads account.

I'm using one of their sample scripts so I presume there cannot be any error there, however the numbers being returned and those in my account do not match.

I want to track the SOAP response/request calls to see if I can pick out any discrepancies but I'm not really sure how to do this. I have installed fiddler2 but how do I set it to pick up the SOAP response/request?

Comment: SOAP requests are xml files so I would filter on Content-Type: application/soap+xml.

Comment: Backing up a bit, it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking: "Hey, I started Fiddler before starting the application using AdCenter, but I don't see the AdCenter traffic?" Or are you saying: "I'm calling AdCenter from an ASP.NET page; how can I configure Fiddler to capture requests coming **from** ASP.NET to a service?" Or something else?

Comment: Hi EricLaw, sorry your right, it is vague. I'm calling the GetMonthlyCosts.php file from the web server which is correctly connecting to the AdCenter API. I'm getting data back and printed to the screen but its not matching. I want to configure Fiddler to capture the request/response between the webserver that the GetMonthlycost.php file is saved on and the the AdCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this. I used SoapUI to test the soap request and make sure it is working correctly.

There is a good tutorial here that describes the basics of soap and how to use SoapUI - http://devzone.zend.com/2202/php-and-soap-first-steps/.

I found this helped allot. I used SoapUI to build a working request and then I used the $client->__getLastRequest() function to check what I was sending was correct.